# How to rewrite this pattern with a simpler structure

Tags: python

I need to do lots of times the following:

```
value1 = kwargs.get('par1')
if value1 is not None: value1 = int(value1)
```

Is it possible to *directly* pass the value returned by `.get` through a filter (`int` in this case), *only* if there is a  match?

I can of course implement a function for this, but I wanted to know if there is a more pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: As others noted below, in your code sample, `par1` isn't defined. Did you mean `value1`?

Comment: Sure, sorry for that. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your own dictionary by extending `UserDict` but you'd need to wrap `kwargs` and that is a bit expensive (not much since `kwargs` is usually small but still ...).

You could always call `int()` and catch the exception but that will be slow as well.

You can't monkey patch `dict` because it's an internal type. Otherwise, you could say `dict.getInt = getAsInt` where `getAsInt` is a new function.

You could use `int(kwargs['par1']) if par1 in kwargs else None` but that will search the dictionary twice.

I'd use a new function for this:

```
def asInt(v): return None if v is None else int(v)

value1 = asInt(kwargs['par1'])
```

Comment: Yes, this looks easy to read. I wonder what is the penalty in terms of performance of calling this function ...

Comment: It's more expensive than the inlined code, of course. But everything else depends on how often you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `if value1 is not None` there:

```
value1 = int(kwargs['par1']) if 'par1' in kwargs else None
```

Comment: This isn't strictly equivalent if `kwargs['par1']` exists and is None itself. (It'll raise in that case, where the original gives None.)

Comment: @Thanatos The code in the question is a little ambiguous, as `par1` is not defined at all.

Comment: True, however, my comment makes the same assumptions as you did in your post. ;-)

Comment: @Thanatos You're right then :) But if it is important, I'd actually the two-line code the OP already has.